# Mini Cooper S JCW R56 (2012) Misfire

Tags: engine, mini-cooper, cylinder

My mini is having an issue with engine msifiring and rpm does not go more than 5 as it starts to tumble. Recently I had a cracked cylinder and changed the whole engine with a less used engine and these issues started. At first it showed the issue of
Fuel tank valve activation line - disconnected
Quality control valve activation line - disconnected

Due to both these reasons the check engine light is showing. And now it has no error codes of misfiring in cylinders.
While starting the car everything is normal but while revving in parked it does not go more than 5 rpm and starts to tumble.
What can go wrong here? each day a new problem rises and we cannot delete these codes in the scanner?
Should we reset the ECU? Is that the problem or something else? Can you please suggest something on this. It would be helpful

Comment: Did you check the intake ports on your new engine?  Carbon buildup on the intake valves is a common problem and can cause the problem you're describing.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Let me check on this and I will get back to you.

Comment: Your question seems a little mismatched. In one part you state you've cleared the codes, then in another you state you cannot delete the codes. Could you clarify things for us a little bit? You could always try to disconnect the negative battery post for 30 minutes then reattach. This will reset all of the trims and logs within the ECU as well as should delete any codes. Anything which pops new after that should be actual.

Comment: HI there, in the software scanner tools we cannot erase these codes. Now the current issue is misfiring in cylinders. Along with other 2(Fuel tank activation line- disconnected and Quality control Valve disconnected)

Comment: Hi there, After 20 days in the garage i received my car back and unfortunately the couldnt fix it and advised me to take it to another garage.

Comment: The check engine light is still on, The current issue is Fuel Tank Valve Activation Line - Disconnected, The mechanics checked for carbon deposit and removed it. They checked the fuel pump pressure was ok and it was alright. They still cannot understand where the faults are. They checked the spark plugs and also the ignition coils.